# Is "/private" just an ordinary directory or does it have special properties

Tags: macos

The nominal links
 /etc --> /private/etc,
 /tmp --> /private/tmp and
 /var --> /private/var 
are all straightforward and I understand they are there because of a legacy need that has passed. Nothing magical about them.

However, I just saw [these install instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/dispatcher-macos-technical-video-setup.html) for an Apache/httpd module which recommend using /private/libexec instead of /usr/libexec. That directory doesn't exist but I can create it via sudo. So, I am wondering if /private has some special properties such that /private/libexec is merged with /usr/libexec?

Comment: Rather than close this - what's magic and ordinary in your title mean? Could you perhaps edit this a bit so it's more clear what we can do to help you out?

Comment: Also, please add a link to the install instructions you are referring to.

Answer (score 5):

There is no magic at works here, this will just create a user-writable directory to store the module in. You can‘t copy it into `/usr/libexec/apache2` as this is protected by SIP.

Using `/private` like this seems kind of odd though. I would probably create `/usr/local/libexec/apache2` and install the module there. You just need to be careful to adapt all references to it as well.